# Reading GUI Data from a Matlab Script File

Tags: matlab, user-interface, user-controls, matlab-guide

I created a GUI named SCADA and I added a boolean variable called StatusData which is a flag that that is set to false when the GUI is launched

```
handles.StatusData=false;
guidata(handles.output,handles);
```

I press a button and then a function is called which executes continuously (the function has infinite loop). After some time I press another button which sets the StatusData to true.

```
handles.StatusData=true;
guidata(handles.output,handles);
```

Now, I need to access the `StatusData` from the callback function (the same function I mentioned above), In order to acheieve this I sent the handle as a parameter when I called that function. Now, When the pressed the button that changes the StatusData, the data in the actual handle changes but I cannot access the updated StatusData as the function is already called.

How can I access the updated handle of GUI without sending it as a parameter.

Thanks

Comment: your description is a bit confusing.. when designing GUIs in MATLAB GUIDE, all callback functions receive the `handles` structure. you can retrieve values from it, as well as set values (just remember to call `guidata` to update them, since `handles` is passed by-value, not as a reference object)

Answer (score 0):

You can just pass in the `hObject` parameter to your function instead, and retrieve your value when it's needed using `guidata`; i.e.,

```
function some_callback(hObject, handles, ...)
    myLoopingFunction(hObject, ...);

function myLoopingFunction(hObject, ...)
    for someVar = something
        % Update handles structure
        handles = guidata(hObject);
    end
```

Alternatively you could create a handle object and put that in the handles structure; e.g.,

```
% In a separate file:
classdef uiState < handle
    % Probably should give this class a less general name...
    properties
        StatusData
    end
end

% In your UI file:
function some_callback(hObject, handles, ...)
    handles.state = uiState();
    handles.state.StatusData = false;
    % Now, when you modify handles.StatusData, the version used by
    % myLoopingFunction will also be updated, because they point to
    % the same object!
    myLoopingFunction(handles.state);

function myLoopingFunction(state, ...)
    for someVar = something
        % Now you just have to check state.StatusData
    end
```

For simple cases, I'd use the first method. For more complicated situations, where several parameters must be kept track of and they interact in complex ways, I would use the second. The second is also useful if you have a large chunk of data in some variable and want to stop it from being copied into every call to the UI.

Personally, for a complex UI I would usually create some application class that keeps track of the user interface (and provides a command-line interface to it) and make sure that was always available to my UI, but that is a bit like using a sledgehammer to open a jam jar in this simple case.